# CSS Tooltip Div and overflow hidden

Tags: tooltip, html, css

I have a sidebar and inside it is a list of items and on some of them I will have a div/tooltip that will appear but I can't get the tooltip to show because of overflow-x:hidden

Is there a way to get `.gps-tooltip` in view where it is in my fiddle?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/Z8KdA/2/)

**html**

```
<div class="menu_side">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="data_gpd" placeholder="That tooltip should be viewable">
                <div class="gps-tooltip">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    min-width: 1009px;
    min-height: 670px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
ul, ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu_side {
    top: 80px;
    opacity: .9;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 10;
}
    .menu_side .wrapper {
        width: 299px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        z-index: 5;
    }
        .menu_side .wrapper li {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width:100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            transition: background .1s ease-in
        }
        .menu_side .wrapper li:hover {
            background: #f0f0f0;
        }


.gps-tooltip {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    position: absolute;
    right: -270px;
    z-index: 15;
    top:0;
}
input[type=text]{
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 700;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                background: #d3d3d3;
                color: #fff;
                display: inline;
                text-align: left;
                text-shadow: none;
                width: 244px;
                padding: 8px;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                border: none;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                outline: none;
            }

.gps-tooltip:after, .gps-tooltip:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.gps-tooltip:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.gps-tooltip:before {
    border-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0);
    border-right-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-width: 11px;
    margin-top: -11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the input field `<input type="text" name="data_gpd" placeholder="That tooltip should be viewable">` isn't supposed to be in the list item of your jsfiddle.

But I made some slight changes to your css, removing the overflow is going to be the first thing you would have to do to make the tooltip appear. As far as I know there is no other way around an overflow hidden.

```
.menu_side .wrapper {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 299px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.menu_side .wrapper li {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 0.1s ease-in 0s;
}
.gps-tooltip {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

Comment: This removes my scrollbar :(